QGIS: Rule-Based Labeling to Show Only One Label per Group of Nearby Points
I am working on a hedge planting project and want only one label to represent each group of similar plants within a certain radius or a set number of nearby points (e.g., 7 points).
I tried using aggregate and rule-based labeling but haven’t achieved the desired result.


You could:
Buffer points - it looks like your points are fairly uniformly spaced, so buffer by their spacing (radius + 1 metre) so they overlap with their neighbour.

Dissolve resulting buffer points, specifying your "abk" field. This will create a separate multipart polygon for each "abk" code. 
Set up the labelling to label each multipart, and set symbology to "no symbology" and you will have something like the below.
Might need to play around with it a bit but hopefully should get you there.
Final points grid
